# How to create a catch-all subdomain in IIS 7.5?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-7, subdomain, iis-7.5, cname-record

How can I create a catchall for any unspecified subdomains of `website.com` in IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 RC2?

I have already configured a CNAME DNS entry for `*.website.com` pointing to `website.com`.

The behavior I am trying to achieve is that any subdomain of `website.com`, such as `foidhfsio.website.com`, will resolve to `website.com`, unless I have specifically defined another site in IIS with the requested host header.

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458757/wildcard-subdomains-in-iis7-is-it-possible-to-make-them-like-it-is-in-apache

Answer (score 5):

Simply leave the host header from the binding empty and it should do the trick.

IIS headers don't support wildcards per se, but if you leave the host header empty, it will catch all traffic for that IP address/port.

The more specific headers from other sites will catch first, so you can just consider this project as the default for your particular IP address.

Comment: Hi, This does work, however, it doesn't catch multiple subdomain somehow.. ex: catches ``mysite.com`` or ``this.mysite.com`` but it doesn't catch ``www.this.mysite.com``

Comment: @iamserious, a 4th level domain functions just the same as any other domain in IIS. If it doesn't work, my guess is that the DNS entry needs to be setup. Try pinging it to ensure that it resolves to the server. The bindings will work the same no matter how many levels the FQDN has.

Comment: I see...  Thanks for the advice, I don't really need it, it's a nice to have feature,  but I'd like to get it to work with www before the subdomain eventually.. will look into it, thanks!